# When there is an embedded clause, is the relative pronoun after it always restrictive?

Tags: usage, relative-pronouns

When there is an embedded clause, is the relative pronoun after it always restrictive?

Or, can it be used as a descriptive relative pronoun?

For example, is ***which*** in the passage used as a descriptive relative pronoun, which can be replaced with ***that***?

> Relativity works as a general mechanism for the mind, in many ways and
> across many different areas of life. For example, Brian Wansink,
> author of Mindless Eating, showed that it can also affect our
> waistlines. We decide how much to eat not simply as a function of how
> much food we actually consume, but by a comparison to its
> alternatives. Say we have to choose between three burgers on a menu,
> at 8, 10, and 12 ounces. We are likely to pick the 10­ounce burger and
> be perfectly satisfied at the end of the meal. But if our options are
> instead 10, 12, and 14 ounces, we are likely again to choose the
> middle one, and again feel equally happy and satisfied with the
> 12­ounce burger at the end of the meal, even though we ate more, ***which***
> we did not need in order to get our daily nourishment or in order to
> feel full.

[Small Change: Money Mishaps and How to Avoid Them](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=xwouDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT28&lpg=PT28&dq=But%20if%20our%20options%20are%20instead%2010,%2012,%20and%2014%20ounces,%20we%20are%20likely%20again%20to%20choose%20the%20middle%20one,%20and%20again%20feel%20equally%20happy%20and%20satisfied%20with%20the%2012%C2%ADounce%20burger%20at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20meal,%20even%20though%20we%20ate%20more,%20which%20we%20did%20not%20need%20in%20order%20to%20get%20our%20daily%20nourishment%20or%20in%20order%20to%20feel%20full.&source=bl&ots=KDDY3-IbmG&sig=ACfU3U1z_ZYVwmHtgWJWE1fRjrlSnjcbHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlls_E4rH5AhWsm1YBHWezA0YQ6AF6BAgcEAM#v=onepage&q=But%20if%20our%20options%20are%20instead%2010%2C%2012%2C%20and%2014%20ounces%2C%20we%20are%20likely%20again%20to%20choose%20the%20middle%20one%2C%20and%20again%20feel%20equally%20happy%20and%20satisfied%20with%20the%2012%C2%ADounce%20burger%20at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20meal%2C%20even%20though%20we%20ate%20more%2C%20which%20we%20did%20not%20need%20in%20order%20to%20get%20our%20daily%20nourishment%20or%20in%20order%20to%20feel%20full.&f=false)

Comment: "Which we did not need in order to get our daily nourishment or in order to feel full" is non-restrictive, so "which" cannot be replaced by "that". Which" has "more " as antecedent: "we did not need more".

Comment: This question should include more details than have been provided here. Please edit to add the research you have done in your efforts to answer the question. See: [Details, Please.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Comment: What @BillJ said. In the exact text as cited, ***which*** (non-restrictively) refers to *the fact of us eating more*, so it can't be replaced by ***that***. But note that if we simply add an explicit noun such as ***food*** after ***more***, this makes it possible to (optionally) apply different syntactic parsing to the utterance, such that the final clause ***is*** restrictive (we ate some food ***that*** we *didn't* need, in addition to perhaps eating some food that we *did* need).